# forwarding not working in iptables from 8006 to 443

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

My dedicated server was bridged to vmbr0 and it has 2 Ethernet cards eth0 and eth1 its bridged.

I have enabled forwarding with `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

I want to redirect the Port 8006 to 443.

Now I'm accessing one of the web applications on port 8006, it want to redirect towards 443 using `iptables`.

Currently I'm using this rule to forward and its not working:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:8006
```

If I apply these `iptables` rules, the page cannot be accessed on 192.168.1.100:8006:

```
# Default filter

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Loopback allows all.

iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Null packets are, simply said, recon packets. see how we configured the VPS and find out weaknesses.

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Reject is a syn-flood attack

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# XMAS packets, also a recon packet

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Allow all Outgoing connection

iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
# Ethernet allows established/related Except invalid.

iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -m state --state ESTABLISHE,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -m state --state INVALID -j DROP

# Allow TCP on Port 22 SSH with rate limiting

iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 5 -j DROP

# Allow Ping ICMP echo With Limiting

iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m recent --update --seconds 10 --hitcount 10 -j DROP

# Allow HTTP Requests for NON-secured 80

iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 20 -j DROP

# Allow HTTP Requests for SLL 443

iptables -A INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 5 --hitcount 20 -j DROP

# Enabling Logging

iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-log:" --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP

# DROP ALL Except Above Rules

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: judging by this previous answer, I'd say you're missing the FORWARD line: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: It's not helped me

Comment: @Lonston, an (ASCII art) diagram with the network would be nice. Also perhaps the `REDIRECT` target wold be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

So much to say, but so little was asked. If you want a remote machine to access something on port 8006 you will have to tell your firewall to accept connections on port 8006, but currently you aren't.

Notice, your rule in PREROUTING modifies segments addressed to 443 and changes that destination address to 8006. You are redirecting port 443 to port 8006. However, you state you want to redirect port 8006 to 443. Maybe changing the numbers in your PREROUTING rule does what you want.

Side note:
You definetly need to rework your firewall script. It apparently is a copy&paste composition of stuff you found somewhere on the internet. While working (now) this is bound to stop working for you. For instance, you set INPUT's policy to DROP but still have `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` at the end of your script. That's redundant and shows you have not given too much thought on the matter. A more critical error is that you enable forwarding, but you have no intention on forwarding ... I think.

Comment: sync flood, xmas, recon pack these are the rules i copied from digital ocean others are typed for long time by own

Comment: So what else i have to provide to get fix this ? could you please guide me

Comment: You need to give a clear description of what you intend to do. Did the numberswapping i suggested help you at all? If not you need to improve your problem description. Not the firewall rules, the problem you want to solve.

Comment: No the port replacement not supported..

Comment: Then "I want to redirect the Port 8006 to 443." is not your only goal. You need to tell us what you have, what you want, what you have tried and what happened during your attempts, especially when you gave up.